# Combining click function and other things

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Can I write this with less code, also is .click(function preferred for mobile or should I use something else?

```
        $('.myclass a').removeClass('class1');
        $('.myclass a').click(function() {
            return false;
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: @undefined's answer is the one you should accept because he's code is the shortest.

Comment: @Victor instead of carry who will get the crown, think of giving upvotes to the ones who really need it. And usually that are the people who ASK questions. And FYI less code `!always=` good code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Chaining](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/). Also, .click works fine for mobile, but you should always test it. There are some exceptions.

```
$('.myclass a').removeClass('class1').click(function() {
        return false;
    });
```

Don't use jQuery Mobile just for click handling, the excessive overhead for just a click is not worth it. Only use it if you have a need for more mobile integration, and if you do, try to only load it when it's needed for mobile.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain the methods:

```
$('.myclass a').removeClass('class1').click(function(event) {
     return false; // event.preventDefault();
});
```

If you are developing for mobile devices, you can consider using jQuery Mobile, which supports events like `tap` and `vclick`.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html